# How important was the train heist in Walt's survival at the hands of Jack's gang in the desert?

Tags: breaking-bad

I have been puzzled the crazy generosity of the out-and-out criminal Jack when the gang had murdered the agents and were taking the barrels of money.

There was a good reason to kill Walt (he was a witness to the murders) and no compelling reason, even having spared him, to leave him with a huge amount of untraceable cash. Jack vaguely talks about Todd admiring Walt and he himself being in a good mood -- it did not make a lot of sense at the time.

But I was just rewatching the scene where Todd very entertainingly recounts the amazing theft of the chemical from the train. Jack and his lieutenant seem to appreciate the story.

The viewers had already seen the train heist in detail -- perhaps they specifically have Todd tell his uncle the story to make Jack's actions towards Walt more plausible?

I think the work they had done for Walt, Todd's genuine admiration for him and perhaps a sense of kinship or direct admiration that Jack had for Walt also contribute (he may see him as cold a murderer as Jack himself is). Not to mention, Walt had in effect given him 70 million dollars, a very, very unexpected windfall even though the gang continues to live in squalor despite this fortune.

To clarify: Was the scene of Todd telling of the train heist included to give Jack a reason to both spare Walt and leave him with a barrel of cash?

Comment: Jack's main reason for sparing Walt is that Todd respects Walt, and that respect is most clearly demonstrated when Todd is telling the story of the train heist... so yeah, probably.